# ReadConsoleOutputCharacter does not work with German umlauts

Tags: .net, winapi, console

I'm using this code to directly read from the Console.

```
    public char? ReadCharacterAt(int x, int y)
    {
        IntPtr consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(-11);
        if (consoleHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var position = new Coord
        {
            X = (short)x,
            Y = (short)y
        };
        var result = new StringBuilder(1);
        uint read = 0;
        if (ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(consoleHandle, result, 1, position, out read))
        {
            return result[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, [Out] StringBuilder lpCharacter, uint length, Coord bufferCoord, out uint lpNumberOfCharactersRead);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Coord
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;
    }
```

However, for German umlauts (äüö) this does not return the correct character. I wonder how can I fix that?

**UPDATE**

As Hans and Raymond pointed out, the answer lays in the DLL import.
All I had to do was changing it to:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

Comment: When you say that it does not return the correct character: What *does* it return? My guess is that since you didn't specify `CharSet=CharSet.Unicode`, you are misinterpreting the code page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SDK docs:

> This function uses either Unicode characters or 8-bit characters from the console's current code page. The console's code page defaults initially to the system's OEM code page. To change the console's code page, use the SetConsoleCP or SetConsoleOutputCP functions, or use the chcp or mode con cp select= commands.

You'll get 8-bit characters since you didn't specify the CharSet in the [DllImport] attribute.  You could technically make it work by reading into byte[] and convert with Console.OutputEncoding.GetString().  But don't, use CharSet.Unicode to have Windows make the conversion for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated my answer to provide the solution. I only had to change the DLLImport to specify the Charset. So it turns out that all the rest (e.g. reading it from the StringBuilder) can actually stay the same. How about updating your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread it. You mean, if I don't specify it I'll have to read it into a byte[] and do the manual work. If I *do* specify it the code can stay as it is. That's what you said, right?